# Data not available error in vlookup: don't know what to do

Tags: excel, vlookup

=VLOOKUP("MA",$M$3:$U$9,3)

[image]

The M3:U9 refers to the table here:

It keeps saying data not available, but I can't figure out why??

Comment: What does `=VLOOKUP("MA",$M$3:$U$9,3,FALSE)` return?

Comment: #N/A. I have no idea what happened

Comment: Is there a trailing space after `MA` in your table?

Comment: No I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your "MA" under "region" have a space after it? If you're getting an error it seems it's not actually "MA" in that box.

Also add a 0 to the end condition to make it an exact match;

`=VLOOKUP("MA",$M$3:$U$9,3,0)`

Comment: I still don;t why tho. isn't it by default?

Comment: "Optionally, you can specify TRUE if you want an approximate match or FALSE if you want an exact match of the return value. If you don't specify anything, the default value will always be TRUE or approximate match."
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: @JiangYuxin - adding `0` or `FALSE` (as I [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303361/data-not-available-error-in-vlookup-dont-know-what-to-do#comment106670455_60303361) a while ago) should be the same result.